# jQueryUI: selectable - cancel option when dragging the lasso over an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

the cancel option on selectable does the following:

> Prevents selecting if you start on elements matching the selector.

Is there a build-in way to make it ignore elements even if you drag over them? Cause with cancel it only works if you start from the element but if you start from a selectable element and drag the lasso over one of the canceled elements it will still select them.

If there isn't a build-in way I guess I have to add it myself with the selecting event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`filter` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#option-filter) with a [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) for this, for example:

```
$(".selector").selectable({ 
  cancel: 'li.cancelClass', 
  filter: 'li:not(.cancelClass)' 
});
```

This prevents those same cancel elements from being selected in the lasso either...they normally *do* get selected because the *default* filter is `*`.

Comment: Thanks again Nick. Strange that sortable uses items and selectable uses filter.